# Setup a VPN on my dedi?

Tags: vpn, ip

Hey, well I have a dedicated server running debian and I'm wondering if it's possible for me to setup a vpn on it, or be able to browse the net using it's ip?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are several vpn options.

http://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/openvpn  OpenVPN

http://wiki.debian.org/IPsec IPsec

http://www.debian-administration.org/article/SSH_dynamic_port_forwarding_with_SOCKS SSH with Socks.

If you just want to browse the net and have web requests come from your debian server, ssh -D localhost:XXXX is the easiest in my opinion.  Just ssh to your server, and then have your browser set to use the localhost:XXXX socks proxy.